# How to fix the error about sbt in the idea IDE?

Tags: scala, sbt

I met a strange error in the idea IDE of the sbt, the merge strategy is as follows,

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {
    case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case m if m.startsWith("META-INF") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList("org", "jboss", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
    case "about.html"  => MergeStrategy.rename
    case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

It seems fine, but unfortunately, the IDE complains one error, it is

```
Cannot resolve reference <<= with such signature
Type mismatch,expected:Def.Initialize[(String) => Plugin.MergeStrategy],  
actual:Def.Initialize[Any].
```

Anyone can explain this to me and how to fix this issue please?

Comment: Does it work fine with sbt ? If yes then ignore intellij idea error.

Answer (score 1):

`mergeStrategy` (and the `<<=` operator) is deprecated. Use `assemblyMergeStrategy` instead:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.startsWith("META-INF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "jboss", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case s => MergeStrategy.defaultMergeStrategy(s)
}
```

Comment: But I can use the "mergeStrategy in assembly := " instead of "assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := "  without any error, why? And when I use  "assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := " . The IDE complains error.

Comment: @Coinnigh What error does it complain about? You can use it because it's only *deprecated*, not removed.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol "assemblyMergeStrategy", is it that the sbt version is not compatible? The version is now 0.13.9.

Comment: Can you upgrade to sbt 0.13.13, just to be on the safe side?

Comment: By the way, how to upgrade it in idea IDE?

Comment: @Coinnigh Go to your `plugin.sbt` file inside the project package, and upgrade the version there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135175/discussion-between-coinnigh-and-yuval-itzchakov).